# Partial derivative with respect to dz

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find $\partial z/\partial x$ and $\partial z / \partial y$ by first obtaining $dz$ for $$x^2+2y^2-z^2=1$$

We have that $$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z} {\partial y}dy.$$

I have thought to separate $z$ so that $$z^2=x^2+2y^2-1$$

and get $z$ on its own so that $$z = \sqrt{x^2+2y^2-1}$$

Then begin taking the derivative:

$$dz=x\sqrt{x^2+2y^2-1}dx+2y\sqrt{x^2+2y^2-1}dy$$

However, the expected answer is
$$dz=\frac{xdx+2ydy}{z}$$

Comment: Is your LHS in expected answer correct? I think it should be $dz$

Comment: @Preet Hi, sorry that was a typo

Comment: Your expression for $z$ is also incorrect: the coefficient of $2$ on the $y^2$ term has disappeared.

Comment: @kipf thank you I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've differentiated incorrectly.
\begin{align*} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2 - 1} \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(x^2 + 2y^2 - 1\right)^{\frac 12} \\
&= \frac 12\left(x^2 + 2y^2 - 1\right)^{-\frac 12} (2x) \\
&= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2 - 1}} \\
&= \frac xz.
\end{align*}
With similar correct operations on $\partial z/\partial y$, you obtain the correct result $$\mathrm dz = \frac xz \; \mathrm dx + \frac{2y}{z} \; \mathrm dy.$$

Comment: Makes total sense, I missed the derivative on the square root